# In dropdown my DataTextField is 00000001 but it show me 1 in selectedvalue

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, data-binding

In dropdown my DataTextField is 00000001 but it show me 1 in selectedvalue

```
Sub MerchantDropDown()

        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds = Utilities.spMerchantName1()
        ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataSource = ds
        ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataTextField = "MerchantName1"
        ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataValueField = "MerchantID"
        ddlMerchantDropDownList.DataBind()
        ddlMerchantDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, "All Merchant")

End Sub
IIf(ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0, "-999", ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedValue()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedValue` will be the value of the `MerchantID` in this case, since you set `DataValueField = "MerchantID"`.

In order to get the value of the `DataTextField`, you need to use:

```
ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text
```

Answer (score -1):

It is default behavior of a drop down list. You can pad zero's after selecting the value from the drop-down list.

```
ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedValue.tostring.padleft(7,"0")
```

More details about [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This is not the default behavior of a DropDownList. It is the behavior of the data type. If you have an integer, yes, 00001 is 1. But if you have a varchar, 00001 will be a 00001. Also, it should be `ddlMerchantDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString().PadLeft(7,"0")` if OP did want to pad.